# Cannot publish nodejs project to azure - could not find a part of the path

Tags: node.js, azure, typescript

I'm trying to deploy a Nodejs project to Azure using a Web Deploy publish profile or FTP profile. The project has TypeScript files in it. The build succeeds. But when I go to deploy I get an error message for a JavaScript file generated by TypeScript:

> Copying file folder\public\app\fc.configuration.js to
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\folder\public\app\fc.configuration.js
>   failed. Could not find a part of the path
>   'folder\public\app\fc.configuration.

How can I publish the site?

The njsproj project file doesn't have a TypeScript section in it.

tsconfig:

```
{   "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"   },   "compileOnSave": true,   "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "packages"   ] }
```

If I double click on the compiler error, it takes me this line in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets:

```
    <CopyPipelineFiles PipelineItems="@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)"
                       SourceDirectory="$(WebPublishPipelineProjectDirectory)"
                       TargetDirectory="$(WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)"
                       SkipMetadataExcludeTrueItems="True"
                       UpdateItemSpec="True"
                       DeleteItemsMarkAsExcludeTrue ="True"
                   Condition="'@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)' != ''">
```

Comment: You can try to refer to http://www.software-architects.com/devblog/2013/02/20/Windows-Azure-Websites--TypeScript--nodejs--JavaScript-on-Steroids, or refer to a sample on Github, at https://github.com/KuduApps/MvcAppWithTypeScript/tree/master/Web

Comment: I get the same issue with the github project @GaryLiu-MSFT. I'll look at the other link provided next

Comment: Looking forward to your news.